# Sum ONLY at the last row where previous rows have same values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: sample data]

Based on the table (image), I have to manually filter the table by fields highlighted in RED or BLUE.
RED - There is more than 1 row which has the same value in those highlighted fields.
BLUE - There is only 1 row with the highlighted fields.

Is there any way I can add the values on the last row where the match vs the previous ends. Like in the attached image you can see the first 2 rows sum is on the 2nd row and likewise.

I have sum-product function but I don't think this function does help.

Any inputs or assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's not a fleshed out answer, but just a conceptual suggestion; consider having additional columns (even if hidden) to keep running totals for each set of matches. E.g. a col where each cell equals this row's fare, unless col E equals the previous row's col E, where they are part of the same set and it instead adds the 'running fare sum' in the cell above to this row's fare, yielding a new fare 'running total'. Finally, whenever col E does differ in the next row, you need to show a total in this row, so you can have a formula pull that row's running total into your final total column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be adjusted as needed.  I am basing logic off column F and summing column H.  Note: This will sum the *entire column H* where F = F of current row.  Selecting only nearby cells and excluding others would need to be a VBA function rather than a formula.

```
=IF(F2=F3,"",IF(F2=F1,SUMIF(F:F,F2,H:H),H2))
```

Or if you want three columns to match (D, E, and F) before it adds up column H:

```
=IF(F2=F3,"",IF(F2=F1,SUMIFS(H:H,D:D,D2,E:E,E2,F:F,F2),H2))
```

Comment: Many thanks Brian, it certainly helped and worked...!!